# Prestashop 1.3.2 FedEx shipping module

Tags: php, prestashop

I'm having a serious problem with a prestashop shipping module for FedEx. I know this might not the place for this, but I'm really running out of options.

First of all Prestashop is an open source E-commerce platform. Now the problem is it has POOR shipping module capabilities. I was on the search for a real time shipping module. I finally found one [**here**](http://www.neboweb.com/blog/prestashop-fedex-module/). I got it to work on the previous version of Prestashop (1.3.1), but upon upgrading to version 1.3.2 the module won't work.

The FedEx module uses two modified core files (Carrier.php and fedexRate.php). And there is the module folder consisting of (blockfedex.php, FedEx-common.php, fedexInstall.sql, RateService_v6.wsdl, RateService_v6-test.wsdl, and rate-test.php)

The prestashop platform is free and easy to install ([**here**](http://www.prestashop.com/en/downloads)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a Fedex module which supports PS 1.3.2 and uses the latest Fedex API.

Check it out at http://www.presto-changeo.com/10-shipping-modules (A UPS module is also available, and USPS is on it's way)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was after I found about your app. It's a small web after all.